# Determine the dimensions for the column space and null space and state the bases in these for all values of a

Tags: linear-algebra

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 3 & 2 & 1\\
        2 & 0 & a & -1 \\
        5 & 3 & 4 & -1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

I've tried converting it into echelon form:
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 3 & 2 & 1\\
        0 & -6 & a-4 & -3 \\
        0 & 0 & -6-2(a-4) & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

But now I'm not really sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing alright so far! Since $-6-2(a-4)=2-2a$, continuing:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 & 1\\
0 & -6 & a-4 & -3 \\
0 & 0 & 2-2a & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} \sim
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 1 & \tfrac{4-a}{6} & \tfrac{1}{2} \\
0 & 0 & 2-2a & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} \quad (\color{red}{*})$$
Now it is clear that you have to distinguish between the cases $a=1$ (zero row) and $a \ne 1$.

Can you take if from there?

---

- In the case of $a=1$, you're looking for the column and null space of:
  $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
          1 & 3 & 2 & 1\\
          2 & 0 & \color{blue}{1} & -1 \\
          5 & 3 & 4 & -1 \\
  \end{pmatrix}$$
  Row reducing shows that the first two columns are pivot columns, so the column space is spanned by the first two column vectors:
  $$\mbox{col}\,A = \mbox{span}\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2 \\ 5\end{pmatrix},
  \begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 0 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$
  These two are linearly independent and thus form a basis. Note that you can obviously simplify the second vector (divide by 3). Can you find a basis for the null space with your usual technique?
- In the case of $a \ne 1$, you can pick up where we left off ($\color{red}{*}$) and divide the last row by $2-2a$:
  $$\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 3 & 2 & 1\\
  0 & 1 & \tfrac{4-a}{6} & \tfrac{1}{2} \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  \end{pmatrix}$$
  You now have 3 pivot columns and the column space is spanned by the first three columns vectors. I'll leave the null space to you again.

Comment: Sorry still not really clear on how to proceed :/

Comment: @Maxposive I updated my answer.

Comment: Ah now I see, thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @Maxposive Alright, you're welcome!